# Access Button Command Parameter value in View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 10 0 0" Name="deluxestack">
        <Button Background="LightGreen" Command="{Binding Status}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"  Width="30" Height="30"  Content="1"/>
        <Button Background="LightGreen" Command="{Binding Status}"  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}" Width="30" Height="30"  Content="2" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
        <Button Background="LightGreen" Command="{Binding Status}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"  Width="30" Height="30"  Content="3" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Above is my code.. how to access these buttons parameter values(contents of the button) in my viewmodel?

EDIT: ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ViewModel() {
      Status = new MyCommand<int>(Receive);
    }
    public ICommand Status {
      get; set;
    }
    private void Receive(int obj) {
      //what should i write here?? 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please show your ViewModel

Comment: public class ViewModel
{

   public ViewModel()
   {
       Status = new MyCommand<int>(Receive);
   }
   public ICommand Status {get;set;} 

   private void Receive(int obj)
  {
      -- what should i write here??      
  }   


}

Comment: Actually i dont know what should i write in the view model..

Comment: It would be a great help, if you could post the `MyCommand` - class too. Dont hestitate to edit your question

Comment: Sorry @lokusking it shows your post has more code add some content.. what should i do? may i post command class in comment??

Answer (score 0):

You can get the passed command parameter as object in your command.

Handle the command in view model like this.

```
Status = new RelayCommand(OnbuttonClick, param => true);
```

Now add the handler as below :

```
private void OnbuttonClick(object obj)
{
   var btnContent = obj.ToString();
}
```

**btnContent** is probably the passed parameter.

**EDIT :**
Added an example for RelayCommand Class

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;
        private Action<int> receive;
        private Func<object, bool> p;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thanks..can you give the  link to get that relay command class??

Comment: Fine.. Hope you got the idea. Read this anyway https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

Comment: it works.. but cant access those four button contents at same time. which means if i click the  button which has content 1, then i can access that 1 alone.. and same for 2,3,4.. cant we access all those four button content as an object in the viewmodel at same time??

Comment: I have added an example of **RelayCommand**. How do you expect to get all 4 button content in a single button click? That doesn't make sense. Maybe you can store the Content data in properties or an array or list as per your requirement.

Comment: so, i can store  the content in list or array in code behind only. right??

Comment: Yes. It’s upto you to keep the data and handle it. 
The normal behavior is when you click the button, you get its command parameter ie the Content

Comment: If you got the point please feel free to mark it as the answer, as it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Yeah.. Actually i am a beginner of mvvm.. so i am trying to do it.